# Select a matrix in a tibble with correct dimensions

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a tibble like this

```
dataf <- as_tibble( matrix(rnorm(12,0,1),nrow=4,ncol=3))
```

Its dimension is `4-by-3`

I created a new column, which itself is a matrix:

```
dataf <- dataf %>% mutate(A = matrix(rnorm(8,0,1),nrow=4,ncol=2))
```

Though `A` is a `4-by-2` matrix, but the dimension of `dataf` is `4-by-4`.

I hope

```
dataf %>% select(A)
```

returns a `4-by-2` tibble, so that I can set names for each column. However, this command still returns a `4-by-1` tibble.

So my question is how this `select` function can return a `4-by-2` tibble? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

wrap the matrix in `I()`

```
    dataf <- as_tibble( matrix(rnorm(12,0,1),nrow=4,ncol=3))
    dataf <- dataf %>% mutate(A = I(matrix(rnorm(8,0,1),nrow=4,ncol=2)))
    dataf %>% select(A) %>% as.matrix
```

If it's acceptable, you have to call `as.matrix` on it to get the actual matrix back

Comment: The output seems to still be 4X1 tibble `# A tibble: 4 x 1
     A[,1]     [,2]...`

Comment: huh you're right. I just saw the two columns and thought that was it. Could call as.matrix on it.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `pull`, which is like the `$` sign in base R.

```
library(dplyr)

A <- dataf %>% pull(A)

class(A)
# [1] "matrix" "array"

dim(A)
# [1] 4 2
```